# Get display name for Zend LDAP Authentication

Tags: zend-framework

I have successfully implemented the [Zend Framework LDAP adapter](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.auth.adapter.ldap.html) for the `Zend_Auth` module, and can login against my Active Directory controller. However, the `getIdentity()` method returns just the username (good for database foreign key usage), while I'd like to (additionally) get the "cn" or "displayname" property of the user object for display on the webpage itself.

I see a `getLdap()` method on the `Zend_Auth_Adapter_Ldap` object, but on the result object from authenticating against Zend_Auth. Is there a way to get at the LDAP connection that the user authenticated with and get their data?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found out a way breaking out of the `Zend_Auth` module and using the `Zend_Ldap` module directly. If anyone knows how to do this using the Auth or AuthAdapter objects, I'd be glad to learn!

I'm using `Zend_Registry` to store various LDAP options, and then the current user information:

Login function:

```
$authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_Ldap(array(
    'server1' => array(
        'host' => Zend_Registry::get('LDAP_host'),
        'accountDomainName' => Zend_Registry::get('LDAP_domainName'),
        'accountCanonicalForm' => 2,
        'baseDn' => Zend_Registry::get('LDAP_baseDn'),
        'bindRequiresDn' => TRUE,
    )
));
$authAdapter->setIdentity($_POST['username']);
$authAdapter->setCredential($_POST['passwd']);
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

// Do the login
$rs = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter);
if (!$rs->isValid()) {
    // Login failed
    exit;
}
// Login succeeded
```

Checking for authenticated user: If we are currently authenticated, create a `Zend_Ldap` object using similar options to the AuthAdapter, and search for this userid.

```
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
    $uid = $auth->getIdentity();
    Zend_Registry::set('cur_user', $uid); // Save username
    $ldap = new Zend_Ldap(array(
        'host' => Zend_Registry::get('LDAP_host'),
        'accountDomainName' => Zend_Registry::get('LDAP_domainName'),
        'accountCanonicalForm' => 2,
        'baseDn' => Zend_Registry::get('LDAP_baseDn'),
        'bindRequiresDn' => TRUE,
    ));
    $ldap->bind();
    $rs = $ldap->getEntry('uid='.$uid.','.Zend_Registry::get('LDAP_baseDn'), array('displayname', 'mail'));
    Zend_Registry::set('cur_user_name', $rs['displayname'][0]);
    Zend_Registry::set('cur_user_mail', $rs['mail'][0]);
} else {
    Zend_Registry::set('cur_user', 'Anonymous');
    Zend_Registry::set('cur_user_name', 'Anonymous');
    Zend_Registry::set('cur_user_mail', 'nobody@nowhere.com');
}
```

Comment: This pretty much is the way to go. Zend_Auth_* ist for AUTHENTICATION purpose. Check credentials, check groups, etc. but don't really do stuff with what you found out.
I really like your way of getting the information, haven't done a lot with LDAP myself i find this to be quite useful!

Comment: With the way that LDAP works, when Zend_Auth attempts to authenticate as the user, it should be "binding" to that user's data in LDAP, and part of the result of that bind should be the additional data from that user's LDAP entry. I shouldn't have to re-bind to that user in order to fetch it.

Comment: Of course it doubles, but that's just the way Zend_Auth works. You could always extend the Zend_Auth and Zend_Auth_Adapter_Ldap with your code to get your result. But to my knowledge there is no inbuilt way to access more.

Answer (score 1):

[Zend_Auth_Adapter_Ldap](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.12/files/Auth.Adapter.Ldap.html) defines a method `getAccountObject` that will do what you want.

eg;

```
$adapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_Ldap($options, $username, $password);

$result = $auth->authenticate($adapter);

if ($result->isValid()) {
   $user_data = $adapter->getAccountObject();
}
```

The method allows you to optionally set which attributes you want to retrieve, too.