# Ldap authentication in php is not working with out zend frame work

Tags: php, zend-framework, ldap

Like normal, `$ds= ldap_connect($host,$port)` is connecting to my server, but I cannot bind the username and password to my ldap server. I tried binding with `ldap_bind($ds,$user,$pwd)`.

I also tried with `ldap_bind($ds,$user.$domainName,$pwd)`.

Then, my client told me that their Ldap server had a `server.username ='INHY_PSB'` and `server.password = 'some_password'`.

This kind of ldap connections are only possible with [zend_php](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.authentication.adapter.ldap.html) class. Now I cannot move my whole project to zend frame work. Is there any way to connect to ldap using zend classes? Please help me to figure out this..

This [code](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.authentication.adapter.ldap.html) was taken from Zend frame work website3

Comment: Have a look at http://adldap.sourceforge.net/ which as far as I understand your problem should work for you.  Either you can use the library to simplify your interaction with ldap, or just have a look at their `connect()` method.

Comment: is there any way to load the zend framework classes and use them, with out installing zend framework..

Comment: i found the **solution**, for using zend classes (with out installing total zend framework) we have to download the zend framework 1.12. and   extract the zend folder which exists inside the library folder...            your code has to look like this link for doing this is [link](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.auth.adapter.ldap.html) helped me  and [link zend is cool to learn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477707/get-display-name-for-zend-ldap-authentication) helps me

Comment: Good if it works for you, although I don't understand your insistence on ripping some code out of a framework to avoid using the framework itself...

Comment: i don't know about zend framework, i read somewhere that zend is having MVC Architecture like Views, controllers, Some so called Procedures. I can't change my whole project  to zend. So, that's why i took [zend 1.123 framework full classes](http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest) Now, my ldap module working like charm... :) :) Thanks for ur support @fvu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of things i learned in [Zend framework 1.12 full package](http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest)

I will simply post my code how i made it work :)

my code file link, you can download here [download and redistribute :)](http://saiportfolio.freeiz.com/stack/e.zip)