# Zend LDAP authentication - How to setIdentity and getIdentity

Tags: php, zend-framework, active-directory, ldap

I am using adldap library to authenticate users against Active Directory. Below is the piece of code I use to authenticate

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

require_once '/adlap/adLDAP.php';

try {
  $adldap = new adLDAP();
}
catch (adLDAPException $e) {
  echo $e;
  exit();   
}

$authUser = $adldap->user()->authenticate($username, $password);
```

How should I **setIdentity** for the user?

In Login system where we store username and password we can setIdentity as mentioned below

```
$adapter = $this->_getAuthAdapter();
$adapter->setIdentity($values['username']);
$adapter->setCredential($values['password']);


protected function _getAuthAdapter() {

        $dbAdapter = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
        $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($dbAdapter);

        $authAdapter->setTableName('users')
                ->setIdentityColumn('username')
                ->setCredentialColumn('password')
                ->setCredentialTreatment('SHA1(CONCAT(?,salt))');


        return $authAdapter;
    }
```

**I am not storing password in Database** and checking it directly against Active Directory. So I couldn't use the above solution.
How shall I setIdentity of users so that I can check if user hasIdentity() like this

```
 $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
  if ($auth->hasIdentity()){
  }
```

I referred the following Stackoverflow question
[Get display name for Zend LDAP Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477707/get-display-name-for-zend-ldap-authentication).
However I am not sure how we shall "get('LDAP_host')" Zend Registry and how should we set it before. Below is the line of code I'm confused with
 'host' => Zend_Registry::get('LDAP_host'),

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

`Zend_Registry::get('LDAP_host')` simply returnes the hostname of your LDAP-Server. Somewhere before that line of code you will find a line similar to `Zend_Registry::set('LDAP_host', 'ldap.example.com')` which sets `ldap.example.com` as LDAP-server.

`getAuthAdapter()` in your case returns an instance of `Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable` but you want an instance of `Zend_Auth_Adapter_Ldap`. So you will have to either call a different method/function `getLdapAuthAdapter()` or rewrite the current method.

```
public function getLdapAuthAdapter() {
    return new Zend_Auth_Adapter_Ldap(array(
        'host'                    => 'ldap.example.com',
        'accountDomainName'       => 'example.com',
        'accountDomainNameShort'  => 'EXAMPLE',
        'accountCanonicalForm'    => 3,
        'username'                => "CN=user1,DC=example,DC=com",
        'password'                => 'pass1',
        'baseDn'                  => "DC=example,DC=com",
        'bindRequiresDn'          => true,
     ));
}

$adapter = $this->getLdapAuthAdapter();
$adapter->setIdentity($values['username']);
$adapter->setCredential($values['password']);
$result = $adapter->authenticate();
```

Hope that somehow helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Will give it a try and let you know how it worked